# Need to add a delete button to a html table to remove record from the database with a message

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, sql-delete

```
<table class="table admin-table list-table nurserytwo-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($nurseries->result() as $nursery) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $nursery->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $nursery->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $nursery->code; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo set_bool($nursery->active); ?></td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> <?php echo 
anchor('admin/nurseries/edit_nursery/'.$nursery->id, 'Edit', 'class="edit-
link"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my current table code and I have had a good look around to see if I can work out how to do this but I am really new to php and can't seem to get my head around it. I need to add a delete button after the edit one and I know I could do this via a delete.php but no idea where to start. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATED:

This is what I have currently:

```
      }elseif( $action == "delete_nursery_course" ){

        if($id) {

            $q = $this->db->where('id', $id)->delete('nursery_courses');
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
                if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
                    $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);
                    echo "SUCCESS"; die();
                }else{
                    set_flash_message('Nursery deleted successfully.', 
'success');
                }
            }else{
                if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
                    $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; die();
                }else{
                    set_flash_message('Something went wrong. Please try 
again.', 'error');
                }
            }
```

And here is the html:

```
<table class="table admin-table list-table nurseryone-table">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Colour</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($nursery_courses->result() as $nursery_course) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $nursery_course->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $nursery_course->name; ?></td>
        <td><div style="background:<?php echo $nursery_course->colour; ?>" 
class="course-colour"></div></td>
        <td><?php echo set_bool($nursery_course->active); ?></td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> <?php echo 
 anchor('admin/nurseries/edit_nursery_course/'.$nursery_course->id, Edit', 'class="edit-link"'); ?></td>
        <td>  
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> <?php echo 
anchor('admin/nurseries/delete_nursery_course/'.$nursery_course->id, 
'delete', 'class="delete-link"'); ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: IS your edit link working?

Comment: It is yeah. Do you want me to post the code?

Comment: yeah that might help.

Comment: So sorry for not coming back. Okay have added what I have currently above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use only html and javascript with jquery to use ajax requests to make an edit and delete button.

HTML:

```
<td class="text-right">
    <a class="edit btn btn-sm btn-default" href="javascript:;">
         <i class="icon-note"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:;">
        <i class="icons-office-52"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

And in your javascript file you have to define the onclick events for this a buttons.

Here's a Plunker example with html and javascript code: 
[Editable Table](https://plnkr.co/edit/sD7LkolzQl1JKGpWF3Ex)

Also you could use jquery DataTables to make it easier and better.

Hope its help you.